# change JavaScript scope

Tags: javascript, with-statement

Is there any posibility to exchange the special global `window` scope by a custom one? I just thought `with` is meant to, but it only stacks another "lookup" scope. Eg.

```
test={};
with(test){
    a=1;
}
```

does not create the property `test.a` but `window.a`.

So the `window` object has a JS-specific special quality I cannot recreate with own code?

Comment: Never thought about needing to do this.  Not needed, but could you elaborate on why this is needed (maybe there is a better solution).

Comment: I like to define functions and variables in a own namespace without using an explicit assignment language like test={'a':1; 'b': function(){...code...});

Comment: No, you can't change the global object.

Comment: Thus it has a special meaning as it is allways targeted by assignments made without earlier declareation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `with` only if the object passed in has that property, will it be modified. It will not be created.

http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2006/04/11/with-statement-considered-harmful/

Answer (score 2):

If the property exists on the object given to `with` then it will be modified, but it will never be created. This is a major "gotcha" with using `with` and the primary reason it should be avoided.

Comment: Yes, a am aware of this flaw of `with`, I just demonstrated that in my question. Now I'm looking for a solution.

Comment: Oh, then my answer should have just been "there isn't one".

Comment: You could (theoretically) write a function that would add the value if it doesn't exist, then just use that function for all declarations.